# Unexpected sub-type

Tags: protobuf-net

Upgraded to v3 from the latest 2.x and getting the error:

```
Unexpected sub-type: Product
```

In the method:

```
internal static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T sourceObject)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, sourceObject);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The `Product` class has the header:

```
[ProtoContract]
public partial class Product : CachableModel, iDeletable, iFilesUploadable, iUserGeneratedContent
```

`CachableModel` has the header:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(Product))]
public abstract class CachableModel : BaseObject, iInstanceType
{
```

And `BaseObject` has the header:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(CachableModel))]
public abstract class BaseObject
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, due to `AsReference` being depricated, serialisation of these properties in Protobuff is no longer possible -  however the error message indicates it's a problem with the model itself and not the `AsReferenced` property.

I can fix this with a lot of refactoring to remove the `AsReference` requirement in my project.

Comment: If you're using `AsReference` anywhere, it *should* have told you about this at build time; inheritance itself has not changed at all.